# DecimalFormat not formatting a double having value equal to 0

Tags: java, formatting, double, number-formatting

I need to format a double to two decimal places and for that i am using DecimalFormat as follows:

```
    Double c = 12.01;
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    System.out.println("c = "+df2.format(c));
```

and it is working very fine until and unless, the double have a 0 (or 0.0, 00.00, or 0.00) value. In that case, it is formatting the double as plane 0 only.

Is there anything which i missed in formatting?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `0` formatting element instead of `#` which involves 0-padding, e.g.

```
Double c = 0.0d;
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
System.out.println("c = "+df2.format(c));
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning 
0       Number      Yes         Digit
#       Number      Yes         Digit, zero shows as absent
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `'##.00'`, as the `#` means optional digit, while `0` means mandatory digit